# Formatting SQL Query Output: Column Header Followed by Value

Tags: sql-server, csv, sqlcmd

Please excuse me if a similar question has been answered elsewhere, but I haven't found it at this point.

I'm trying to format the results of a SQL Server query (via sqlcmd) so that the output is a CSV file with the column header first, followed by the value. The query will only ever return one record's values.

As an example, here's a record I could expect to pull from the table:

```
InputFileName InputFileSizeBytes JobId Steps NumSteps
------------- ------------------ ----- ----- --------
TestData.dat  1024               32768 1     2
```

With this data, I would want to generate a CSV file that looks like this:

```
InputFileName,TestData.dat
InputFileSizeBytes,1024
JobId,32768
Steps,1
NumSteps,2
```

So far, nothing I've come up with has worked. For instance, I attempted to `UNION` the values with constant strings, as well as give them an order:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 'InputFileName' AS InputFileName,
       'InputFileSizeBytes' AS InputFileSizeBytes,
       'JobId' AS JobId,
       'Steps' AS Steps,
       'NumSteps' AS NumSteps,
       'ClientEmailMessage' AS ClientEmailMessage,
       'ClientContactInfo' AS ClientContactInfo,
       'DTInQueueUTC' AS DTInQueueUTC,
       1 AS ordering
    FROM HS_JOB_QUEUE
UNION
SELECT InputFileName, 
       InputFileSizeBytes, 
       JobId, 
       Steps, 
       NumSteps, 
       ClientEmailMessage, 
       ClientContactInfo, 
       DTInQueueUTC,
       2 AS ordering
    FROM HS_JOB_QUEUE
    WHERE JobId = 79000
ORDER BY ordering;
```

This did not work at all - sqlcmd spat out an error saying the constants could not be used in a `UNION` operation.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Nice job posting details. But as you suspected this has been asked. What you need is an unpivot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would I need to unpivot each column, or would one unpivot suffice?